# TI3 - Why go for Spec Ops Training?

Tags: twilight-imperium, twilight-imperium-3rd-edition

In Twilight Imperium, the Federation of Sol have been given this as their secondary race tech:

> Spec Ops Training (5)  Each time you roll a 1 during Invasion Combat,
>   you  may reroll the die. You must use the second result.

Notice that this is not the same as e.g. +1 to all Ground Forces combat rolls. With a smashing price of 5 additional resources, I am looking for the reason why this race tech is even in the game...

I have some questions to add to this:

- It's not worded for combat rolls specifically. Does this apply to Gen Synthesis and Dacxive Animators rolls too (since Federation of Sol seem to be taking good care of their ground forces)?
- Does this apply to Mechanized Units?
- Will this apply to Fighters as well, when Sol gains the Graviton Negator tech?

If it's only half a +1 to Ground Forces, why would anyone buy it?

Comment: The consensus seems to be that while this tech is unimpressive, Sol is strong enough in other departments to make up for it.  So it's "even in the game" for balance purposes, really, rather than because it's a desirable power...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In response to your three sub-questions and adhering strictly to rules as written (RAW):

Ad 1: No, you would not get the bonus for these two techs (Gen Synthesis and Dacxive Animators) as they both happen at the end of invasion combat which is outside the scope of the wording on the card.

Ad 2 and 3: Since the card does not state that it only provides its ability to ground forces but rather is a universal rule during invasion combat, I would say, yes it applies to both Mech units and Fighters with Graviton Negators since these are rolls that happen during invasion combat.

Answer (score 3):

Dacxive Animators happens at the end of combat but Gen Synthesis happens at the end of each round of invasion combat. Thus, it's possible that Special Ops training would work with Gen Synthesis.